# Hard Real Analysis Problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers that are diﬀerent from zero. Assume that the following limit exits 
$$\alpha := \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ |x_{n+1}|}{ |x_{n}|}, $$ and $$0 \le \alpha \lt 1.$$

Let $0 \le α \lt β \lt 1.$

Prove that there exist a constant $$C \gt 0$$ such that   $$|x_{n}| \le C \beta^{n},$$ $\forall\, n \in N$

Conclude that $x_n \to 0.$

1. Is this correct?

   $\exists k \in N$ such that
   $$ \frac{ |x_{k+1}|}{ β} \leq |x_k| .$$

   So, for $C = |x_k|$ and $n \in N$ such that $n > k$
   $$ \frac{ |x_{n}|}{β^n} \leq \frac{ |x_{n-1}|}{β^{n-1}} \leq\ ...\ \leq
     \frac{ |x_{2}|}{ β^2} \leq \frac{ |x_{1}|}{ β} \leq C .$$
   Thus $|x_n| \leq |x_k|β^n\ \ \forall n \in N$ and $x \rightarrow 0.$

Comment: Could someone please help me out on where to begin with this problem?

Comment: Beta is useless.

Comment: this is a rather useless title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Since 
\begin{align}
\frac{|x_{n+1}|}{|x_n|} \rightarrow \alpha
\end{align}
then there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have
\begin{align}
\frac{|x_{n+1}|}{|x_n|}\leq \beta
\end{align}
where $\beta>\alpha$.

See what you can say about $x_{n+k}$.